# LWJGL Objects not shown on ATI graphics card

Tags: opengl, shader, lwjgl

I've written an LWJGL application that uses .obj files, reads them and displays them (using displaylists).

On my nvidia graphics card, everything runs fine. But on an amd graphics card i can't see the objects.

How i give data to the shaders:

```
glUseProgram(shaderEngine.obj);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderEngine.obj, "inOrangeJuice"), inOrangeJuice ? 1 : 0);
shaderEngine.loadMatrix(glGetUniformLocation(shaderEngine.standard, "projectionMatrix"), camera.projectionMatrix);
shaderEngine.loadMatrix(glGetUniformLocation(shaderEngine.obj, "viewMatrix"), camera.viewMatrix);
```

ModelMatrix is loaded:

```
shaderEngine.createModelMatrix(new Vector3f(x, y, z), new Vector3f(rx, ry, rz), new Vector3f(1, 1, 1));
shaderEngine.loadModelMatrix(shaderEngine.obj);
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 130

uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform vec2 texCoord[4];

float textureSize;
float texelSize;

uniform int inOrangeJuice;


bool pointInTriangle(vec3 P, vec3 A, vec3 B, vec3 C)
{
    vec3 u = B - A;
    vec3 v = C - A;
    vec3 w = P - A;

    vec3 vCrossW = cross(v, w);
    vec3 vCrossU = cross(v, u);

    if(dot(vCrossW, vCrossU) < 0)
    {
        return false;
    }


    vec3 uCrossW = cross(u, w);
    vec3 uCrossV = cross(u, v);

    if(dot(uCrossW, uCrossV) < 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    float denom = length(uCrossV);
    float r = length(vCrossW);
    float t  = length(uCrossW);

    return (r + t <= 1);
}


vec4 texture2DBilinear(sampler2D textureSampler, vec2 uv)
{
    vec4 tl = texture2D(textureSampler, uv);
    vec4 tr = texture2D(textureSampler, uv + vec2(texelSize, 0));
    vec4 bl = texture2D(textureSampler, uv + vec2(0, texelSize));
    vec4 br = texture2D(textureSampler, uv + vec2(texelSize , texelSize));
    vec2 f = fract( uv.xy * textureSize );
    vec4 tA = mix( tl, tr, f.x );
    vec4 tB = mix( bl, br, f.x );
    return mix( tA, tB, f.y );
}


void main()
{
    ivec2 textureSize2d = textureSize(tex,0);
    textureSize = float(textureSize2d.x);
    texelSize = 1.0 / textureSize;

    //texture coordinate:
    vec2 texCoord = (gl_TexCoord[0].st);

    bool inOJ = false;

    if(inOrangeJuice == 1)
    {
        float depth = gl_FragCoord.z / gl_FragCoord.w;//works only with perspective projection
        depth = depth / 6;

        if(depth > 1)
        {
            depth = 1;
        }
        inOJ = true;
        gl_FragColor = texture2DBilinear(tex, texCoord) * gl_Color * (1.0 - depth) + vec4(1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0) * depth;
    }
    if(inOJ == false)
    {
        gl_FragColor = texture2DBilinear(tex, texCoord) * gl_Color;
    }

    //Nothing is shown, inOrangeJuice should be 0
    //gl_FragColor = vec4(inOrangeJuice,0,0,1);

    //Always works:
    //gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex, texCoord) * gl_Color;
}
```

Comment: Anything in the shader compilation/link logs?  Those `0`s and `1`s may need to be `0.0`s and `1.0`s.

Comment: How can i display those logs? There is no compilation error, that would be shown but i don't display anything else.

Comment: On AMD i get: "Validation warning! - Sampler value tex has not been set."

Comment: i of course meant ATI